# Ошибка Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalDate'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Пытаюсь импортировать модуль `import java.time.LocalDate;`, однако программа ругается

> Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalDate'

я так понимаю его надо каким то образом установить в jdk ?

[image: Описание ошибки]

Comment: Какую версию JDK вы используете? [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) появился в Java 1.8.

Comment: JDK 17 и JDK 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) из пакета `java.time` представлен в Java начиная с версии 1.8 (JDK 8 и выше). Убедитесь, что используете версию JDK 8 или выше.

Если по какой-то причине у вас нет возможности использовать JDK 8+, то используйте альтернативные библиотеки, которые предоставляют схожий функционал. Например, библиотека [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Если у вас уже установлена JDK 8+, то, возможно, у вас какие-то неполадки со средой разработки, попробуйте [почистить кэш](https://sbytestream.pythonanywhere.com/blog/How-to-fix-IntelliJ-cannot-resolve-symbol) в IntellJ IDEA: выберите в меню `File` → `Invalidate Caches` → `Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: Проверил через консоль            java -version
java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: А как вы компилируете приложение, через ту же консоль?

Comment: Нет через идею, по ветке Project Structure → Project Settings → Project    SDK = 19.0.1   Language level = SDK default  проверил

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить в коде `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));`, какое значение распечатается?

Comment: Пока не могу )) я видимо сделал что то фатальное когда решил переустановить JDK )) теперь любой импорт так ругается и ничего не запускается) System.out.println -> Cannot resolve method 'println(String)' теперь тоже -_-

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, проблему решила очистка кэша.  статья http://sbytestream.pythonanywhere.com/blog/How-to-fix-IntelliJ-cannot-resolve-symbol

Comment: @Владимир, отлично! Добавлю вашу ссылку в ответ для полноты ответа.